# How to extract data inside an xml tag with the same name as another tag in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tags

everyone! I am trying to create an application that uses Google's Geocode API (XML). This is the XML data that I am working with:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <type>university</type>
  <formatted_address>77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>77</long_name>
   <short_name>77</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Massachusetts Avenue</long_name>
   <short_name>Massachusetts Ave</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Area 2/MIT</long_name>
   <short_name>Area 2/MIT</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Cambridge</long_name>
   <short_name>Cambridge</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Middlesex County</long_name>
   <short_name>Middlesex County</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Massachusetts</long_name>
   <short_name>MA</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>02139</long_name>
   <short_name>02139</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>42.3600910</lat>
    <lng>-71.0941600</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>42.3587420</lat>
     <lng>-71.0955090</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>42.3614400</lat>
     <lng>-71.0928110</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJh2oa9apw44kRPCAIs6WO4NA</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I am trying to work through the XML data to extract the county:

```
<address_component>
   <long_name>Middlesex County</long_name>
   <short_name>Middlesex County</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
```

However, other tags in the XML data use the same name of "address_component" and "long_name". Due to the fact that there are no attributes associated with these tags, I can't find the specific data I want. Can anyone please help me how to go through the XML data using python and find the exact data I need despite the fact that the tags have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is getting the `address_component` with a subelement `type=administrative_area_level_2`, you can iterate the XML and select the desired element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("your xml string")

def find_by_tag(tag, add_type= "administrative_area_level_2"):
    for address in root.iter("address_component"):
        if address.find("type").text == add_type:
            return address.find(tag).text
    return None
```

You can get `long_name` by using function `find_by_tag`:

```
find_by_tag("long_name")
## 'Middlesex County'
```

Or other tags, e.g.:

```
find_by_tag("short_name")
## 'Middlesex County'
find_by_tag("short_name", "postal_code")
## '02139'
```

Comment: Thanks for that information! I have found the chunk of XML code I've been trying to get. However, how do I work with it? I've tried a lot of different find functions to get the "long_name" tag, but it is not working. It seems as if I am getting confused on what to do next, so could someone please explain how I should go on with this data! Thanks to Huang who has replied so far!

Comment: @RaamizAbbasi I edited my answer. Hope it works for you.